# the Meaning of ... [CLOSED

Tags: ios, xcode

This is stupid, but i have to know how ( % ) sign means, because i want to add days.

this is an example.

```
int seconds = 78120;
int forHours = (seconds1 / 3600),
    remainder = (seconds1 % 3600),
    forMinutes = remainder / 60,
    forSeconds = remainder % 60;
    NSString *Time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i:%02i",forHours,forMinutes,forSeconds];
    Label.text = Time;
```

**Result:
21:42:00**

i want the result to be like (  **0 days, 21:42:00** ) like ( **DD, HH:mm:ss** )

Comment: Where did you get this code? If you don't know what `%` does, how do you know you want to use it?  Your actual question, "i have to know how ( % ) sign means, because i want to add days", perplexes me.

Comment: Where i get this code? from this site..

Comment: ( % ) sign is the only one that i did not know what it meant..

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: i just want this to get deleted sorry for that.

Answer (score 10):

It's called the [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). It's whats left when you divide a number (and only take into account whole numbers).

Examples:

```
3 % 2 = 1
6 % 2 = 0
6 % 3 = 0
6 % 4 = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

% (modulo) gives the remainder after division.

So you can add the separation for days at the start, then use modulo to get the number of seconds after removing those accounted for in days:

```
int seconds = 78120;
int days = seconds / 86400;

// Equivalent to: seconds = seconds - days * 86400 /*# seconds in a day*/;
seconds = seconds % 86400; // seconds remaining less than a day

int forHours = (seconds1 / 3600),
    remainder = (seconds1 % 3600), // seconds remaining within an hour
    forMinutes = remainder / 60,
    forSeconds = remainder % 60; // seconds remaining less than a minute
```

Answer (score 2):

The modulus (%) operator returns the remainder of the integer division.

a = 13 % 5;

Here, a will equal 3.

Try:

```
int fordays = seconds1 / 86400,
    remainder = seconds1 % 86400,
    forHours = remainder / 3600,
    remainder = remainder % 3600,
    forMinutes = remainder / 60,
    forSeconds = remainder % 60;
```

1 day = 86400 seconds.